# StopWatch#stop(), throwing NPE

Tags: spring-mvc

while working on `interceptor` with `SpringMVC` I'm getting `NPE`. I am using `log4j.properties` and here is the following code of `interceptor`

```
 ThreadLocal<StopWatch> stopWatchLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object,
            Exception exception) throws Exception {
        StopWatch stopWatch = stopWatchLocal.get();
        stopWatch.stop();//Line 24
        logger.info("Total time taken for processing: " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " ms");
        stopWatchLocal.set(null);


    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Request processing ended on " + getCurrentTime());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch(object.toString());
        stopWatch.start(object.toString());
        stopWatchLocal.set(stopWatch);

        logger.info("Accessing URL path: " + getURLPath(request));
        logger.info("Request processing started on: " + getCurrentTime());
        return true;
    }

    private String getCurrentTime() {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    private String getURLPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String currentPath = request.getRequestURI();
        String queryString = request.getQueryString();
        queryString = queryString == null ? "" : "?" + queryString;
        return currentPath + queryString;
    }
```

this is the `log`

j

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.webstore.interceptor.PerformanceMontiorInterceptor.afterCompletion(PerformanceMontiorInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.triggerAfterCompletion(HandlerExecutionChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1023)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
```

interceptor in **dispatcherServlet**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="com.package.InterceptorClass"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

Am I doing something wrong ?
Please Help, is my configuration is broken because I'm not able to get the answer why I am getting NPE

Comment: Use a filter instead and don't store it in a thread local. It could be that a thread gets switched out for the after completion. Probably easier to store it in the request as a request attribute instead of a threadlocal. Next to that which line is line 24?

Comment: @M.Deinum thaks for reply, my bad I made a edit and removed reference to `NPE` its ` stopWatch.stop();` under method `afterCompletion(..)`

Comment: @M.Deinum can you provide any sample so i can start working on it

Comment: ThreadLocal variable is used to store the data/object per thread. So it is not guaranteed that your preHandle and afterCompletion methods are called in same thread. If this happens, your stop watch instance will be null and you will get null pointer. You may want to store StopWatch instance in request as suggested by @M.Deinum or. You can maintain a Hashmap of Request and StopWatch in your Interceptor instead of Threadlocal. But if you want monitor performance of Methods, there are better libraries available like **DropWizard Metrics**.

Comment: @M.Deinum since it resembles with `springAOP` will that be good if I go by using `AOP` instead of `interceptor` (just a querry) thanks